# Twilio Liquid Template cant access array

Tags: twilio, liquid, liquid-template, twilio-flow

I am running into an issue where i use {{flow.data.Schedule | split:"~"}} to create an array with the variable name "schedule". I am trying to access the first value in the array but using {{flow.variables.schedule[0]}} and it comes out as nothing.
[image]

edit:

according to the logs it doesnt look like its creating the array after I use the split.
"schedule": "Monday through Friday from 12:30 AM to 1:00 AM  Monday from 3:00 PM to 4:00 PM and Wednesday from 1:00 PM to 2:00 PM",

when original value has a "~" in the middle of that. the split removes it but doesn't seem to create an array.

edit 2:

I tried with a normal string "What~are~you" and in the logs its shows as "Whatareyou" after the split. I think the split function is not working as I expect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The split function cannot be used inside the set variable widget.

Example inside a say/play:

Hello, {% assign array = flow.variables.schedule | split: '~' %}

{{array[0]}}

Answer (score 0):

The reason this may be happening is because your variable names are case-sensitive. In your Set Variable widget, you are defining the variable as `flow.data.Schedule` (with a capital 'S'). In your next widget, you are trying to access the variable by saying `flow.variables.schedule[0]` (with lowercase 's').

Reference: https://www.twilio.com/docs/studio/widget-library/set-variables#required-configuration-for-set-variables